# Using `inference_schema.schema_decorators` with dynamic `numpy` array shape

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

**Question summary**

I'm deploying a model to an Azure Container Instance, using the Azure Machine Learning Service API. Specifically, the model is a PyTorch (fastai) model classifying images of varying shapes.

Microsoft provides some nice decoraters to handle input and output data schemas in the scoring script. However, I am unable to figure out, if it's possible to use the `NumpyParameterType` with dynamic shape for the input.

**Scoring script**

A sample of the scoring script:

```py
import pickle
import json
import numpy as np
import time
import os

from PIL import Image as PilImage
from azureml.core.model import Model
from inference_schema.schema_decorators import input_schema, output_schema
from inference_schema.parameter_types.numpy_parameter_type import NumpyParameterType

def preprocess_inference(img):
    # Preprocessing handled here

def make_prediction(data_preprocessed):
    # Model prediction handled here

def init():
    global model

    model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name='my_pytorch_model',
                                      version=1)

    # Get paths
    split_path = model_path.split('/')

    model = fastai.load_learner(path = '/'.join(split_path[:-1]), file = split_path[-1])

# How to use the schema decoraters with dynamic size?
input_sample = np.array(PilImage.open('src/deployment/test/test_image.png'))
output_sample = np.array([0, None], dtype=np.object)

@input_schema('raw_data', NumpyParameterType(input_sample))
@output_schema(NumpyParameterType(output_sample))
def run(raw_data):

    try:

        data_preprocessed = preprocess_inference(raw_data)

        prediction = make_prediction(data_preprocessed)

        return prediction

    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        print (error + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        return error
```

Which only works if the image uploaded has the exact same shape as 'src/deployment/test/test_image.png'. Right now my solution is to avoid the decoraters and do the data interpretation myself.

```py
def run(raw_data):

    try:

        img = np.array(json.loads(raw_data)['raw_data'], dtype=np.uint8)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)

        data_preprocessed = preprocess_inference(img)

        prediction = make_prediction(data_preprocessed)

        return prediction

    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        print (error + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        return error
```

But it would be nice to be able to use the decorators, such that endusers can benefit from the nice warning messages as well.

Answer (score 1):

The NumpyParameterType class has an `enforce_shape` parameter to the constructor that can be set to False to allow for dynamic array size:

`@input_schema('raw_data', NumpyParameterType(input_sample, enforce_shape=False))`

This may still have some strange interactions depending on how you are passing the image data into the service, however. We are working on a parameter type that could be used for better image handling, but don't have it yet.

Comment: "> We are working on a parameter type that could be used for better image handling, but don't have it yet."

4 years later, is that a thing?

Comment: No, unfortunately it was never fully funded, and now work has pivoted in a different direction for handling of these decorators in general. I'll pass this on to the folks doing that work, they can speak to whether or not they plan to natively support images in some way.